# Vscode default website 500 error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code

My apologies if this is something simple but I cannot seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

I've set up VSCode on my macbook, and used yeoman to scaffold a default website (without authentication). I can build the project fine, but when I run and try to browse to it I'm getting a 500 error.
There is no response data so I can't get any more information than that, and the fact that it's Kestrel server.

I've also tried browsing to /home and /home/index etc but nothing

I'm hoping this is something simple that other people have encountered, and that there's an easy fix...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look at server logs to find out the cause of an Internal Server Error.

Comment: I can't find anything in apache logs... does kestrel have it's own logs? and do you know where they are ?

Comment: For anyone else who may run into this, frankly I'm not entirely sure what fixed the problem, but:

* I uninstalled Xamarin, which I also had installed
* I uninstalled mono
* I uninstalled VSCode
* I reinstalled everything EXCEPT Xamarin

The only other thing I did, was that I assumed (since it isn't said anywhere) that .Net Next was included in VSCode, but I installed that separately 

So, not sure which of these steps fixed it, whether I didn't have .net next which was required, or perhaps there were mono conflicts between VSCode and Xamarin but maybe this will be useful for someone else

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may run into this, frankly I'm not entirely sure what fixed the problem, but: * I uninstalled Xamarin, which I also had installed * I uninstalled mono * I uninstalled VSCode * I reinstalled everything EXCEPT Xamarin The only other thing I did, was that I assumed (since it isn't said anywhere) that .Net Next was included in VSCode, but I installed that separately So, not sure which of these steps fixed it, whether I didn't have .net next which was required, or perhaps there were mono conflicts between VSCode and Xamarin but maybe this will be useful for someone else

Comment: Hi @richardterris Did you try to change the environment variables to "Development" to show the errors details?